# Clunking Sound in 2008 Chevrolet Malibu

Tags: chevrolet, noise, malibu

I recently made a post about a sound coming from the front end of my 2008 Chevrolet Malibu. The sound occurs when I accelerate fast or break harder. It also makes the noise when I go slowly over bumps. The other time it makes the sound is when I go around a corner and when I pull out of the turn and correct the steering. It seems to occur when I finish turning my steering wheel back into the correct position and accelerate out of the turn. The sound is only ever one "clunk". I'm reposting because symptoms have changed a bit. I also want to point out the previous owner just had the CV Joints changed. My thoughts are leaning towards a ball joint. I would love someone's opinion before I take it to a mechanic and I can get some ideas.

Comment: I agree might be a ball joint but look at the swaybar links also. Ball joints tend to do the single clunk while swaybar  links may rattle or pop depending on the design.

Comment: Instead of reposting a new question, please edit the old question since it's the same issue.